# Is there way to improve R sound in audio?

Tags: audio, voice, sound-editing, voice-manipulation, audio-restoration

If you need to get a sharper R on the audio track, to make it sound [more Spanish](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=es&tl=en&text=se%C3%B1orita). To make without selecting each instance or the sound. I.e. is it possible to apply some settings to the whole audio so that all Rs would sound sharper?
I think such settings can be application neutral, but just in case - preferably for Audacity.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to lift consonants, you have to push back the vowels, otherwise things can just get 'fizzy'.

You could try this with EQ - lifting somewhere between 1 - 4kHz, but I think that's more likely to over-emphasise T's & S's than R's, resulting in 'fizzy'.

I'd go for a compressor - particularly a multiband compressor.
This will allow you to selectively compress vowels & pick out consonants without it all being too obvious it has been done.
R's are likely to be lower than T's & S's, so you could work around 800-1.5k without over-emphasising above there. If it's still hard to separate, you can even pre-EQ, so you hit the comps harder or softer at certain frequencies, then use the comp to also de-ess a bit if you get cross-over.

This is all far easier to do whilst twiddling faders than to try to explain in text ;)

It's hard to get a screenshot of this in action, so I wound up the comps really hard to try catch an extreme bit of compression… In 'real' use these curves are likely to be much less extreme & very fleeting.

[image]

[image]

This is Waves' Linear Phase Multiband compressor & Limiter/maximizer, both doing a similar task in slightly different ways [though not simultaneous screen captures]. Not the cheapest available, but lovely to use & easy to visualise what's happening to your audio.

These settings are actually what I have on my HTPC 'home theatre' to keep speech nice & clean even when they're whispering, yet prevent car chases & explosions annoying the neighbours, which is why they're quite so extreme - they have to handle an entire finished soundtrack, not just a voice. The images were taken during simple indoor dialog, to give a better impression of how they reshape a voice track.